# What size was the Mizrak to catch blood in the Beis Ha'Mikdash?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, korban, size, keilim

The Gemorah .זבחים כה says that the Cohen receiving the blood of a korbon must catch all the blood. That is the Dam HaNefesh - the blood flowing out of the neck.

Assuming the average cow has around 10 gallons of blood, and assuming it must lose around 25% of it to die, the Mizrak would have to be at least 2.5 gallons. This is not what I pictured, considering also that the Cohen holds it with only one hand.

Does anyone know of a source for the size of a Mizrak used in the Beis Ha'Mikdash?

Comment: How do you know dam hanefesh is 25% of a cow's total blood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Talmud, also in Zevachim later on ([97b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zevachim.97b.8?with=all&lang=bi)), identifies the biblical '*mizrak*' with the '*agan*' (אגן); see also [Ex. 24:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.24.6?with=all&lang=bi&aliyot=0). Elsewhere in the Talmud (Ber. [22a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.22a.23?with=all&lang=bi)), the *agan* is depicted as a tub that can contain enough water to bathe in (9 kav; aprox. 3 gallons). (In biblical descriptions they are both typically used to illustrate large, excessive/exaggerated quantities (e.g. the former Amos 6:6; the latter Cant. 7:3).)

Furthermore, a *midrash* (BR [13:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Bemidbar_Rabbah.13.14?with=all&lang=bi)) equates the volume of the *ka'arah* and the *mizrak*, in which the former symbolically contained the ocean and the latter contained dry land (both an illustration of great quantity).